# How to create big reflective dark glass

Tags: modeling, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

Respect for all answers i got on this forum these years. From programming to blender. Now I need a bit specific help.

I need to texture my object that looks like this(black shiny glas) [image]
or this  [image]

Tx for this(PS:I am a beginner)

Comment: In Cycles Render I guess you will mainly use a Glossy node with very dark color and small Roughness

Comment: Most of the work will be in the lighting/environment

Answer (score 4):

If you are a beginner, an easy shader to get good results will be the Principled BSDF, it's a little different than other shaders, you can google it to know more, here is a example:

[image]

Keep in mind that if you want glossy objects to look good or realistic, you will need reflections from somewhere, in my example I used a HDRI map to my world shader, I post here to help any guys out there, but it's not a beginner node tree mind you. Essentially what you want is, a image texture to light your scene and also reflect on it.

[image]

For you to better understand HDRI maps, maybe these links will help you:

https://www.hyperfocaldesign.com/tutorials/blender-hdri-tutorial-cycles/

https://www.creativeshrimp.com/hdr-lighting-in-blender.html

https://blenderartists.org/t/beginner-professional-lighting-in-blender-2-78-using-hdri/677353

http://hdrmaps.com/blog/blender-hdri-setup/

Hope it helps,

**Edit:** Here's the file with a better bench topology,

[image]

Notice that for you to access the world shader, you need to click on the little globe icon in the node editor. That's where the magic happens with HDRIs.
[image]

Also I packed the HDRI maps in the blend file. But If you or anyone reading this, want some free quality HDRIS, here a great source:

https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/

Cheers,

Comment: You are definitly Black Chess KIng. This is really helpful. That bench looks really nice and i am gonna check links. Is this bench your project It will be definitly huge help if you can send me file, to check it. I am doing something similiar and insights in this bench could help me a lot. Thanks man

Comment: Just edited the post, hope it helps.

Comment: If I'm reading your tree right, it gives you the _option_ of balancing the strengths of lighting and reflection contributions of the (directly unseen) subway HDRI, while  the garage HDRI is what's visible in the background? But while all the strengths are set to 1, that option isn't being taken, so if that works, you could lose the first mix node, and just keep the second? I just think that might help explain what's going on to @dubai0,if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes, my tree respectively has 3 components, Background, Lighthing and Reflection, the mixes are done using the camera ray information to mix these shaders, with this, I can  control each component separately. While their strengths are set to 1, that's my default value for a starting point, you can tweak however you want. You can see the background doesn't match the lightings and reflections, that was not important because I made the render transparent, if however one would like to render the background, he can input a map and render it correctly with the rest of the components.

Comment: Finally I would like to explain what are the strengths, they are not mixing the shaders, they're just controlling the brighteness of the maps, if you use HDRI maps, you need to control their exposure, and that's an easy way of doing that. The mixes are using camera rays to mix, it works like a boolean operator, for example, the first mix, Lighthing and Reflection, are separated by the Camera Ray node, which is separating the reflection, hence it says: "Is Glossy Ray", so the first shader attached to that mix, will be only the lighthing, and the second one, the gloss only, or reflections.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cycles and try this node configuration for the material:
[image]

Changing the Glass BSDF Color value to brighter will make the glass more transparent, if you need it.

Remember to use an environment map for the world background color.
If you are new to nodes look first at some basic tutorials on Youtube.

Comment: I will try this setup.Tx for response